# Random seeds and multithreading in numba

Tags: python, multithreading, numba, random-seed

I wondered if there is any way to reproducibly draw random numbers when using `parallel==True` with jitted functions in numba. I know that for singlethreaded code, you can set the random seed for numpy or the standard random module within a jitted function, but that does not seem to work for multithreaded code. Maybe there is some sort of workaround one could use?

Answer (score 0):

In parallel, each worker need to have its own seed as a random number generator cannot be both efficient and and thread safe at the same time. If you want the number of threads not to have an impact on the result, then you need to split the computation in chunks and set a seed for each chunk (computed by one thread). The seed chosen for a given chunk can be for example the chunk ID.

Comment: One could have the program start with a single seed for a single PRNG that it uses to generate seeds for the per-thread PRNGs. OTOH, one of the "features" of threads is that the interleaving of their operations is unpredictable most of the time. \*IF\* OP needs the program to always produce the same result when given the same seed, and \*IF\* different interleavings cause "different" results, then the OP may be frustrated.

Comment: For the first part, this is not needed because a good RNG should not generate a better sequence with seeds like 0,1,2,...,n than with random values generated from another initial seed, and in the end it also make the code more complex. For the second part, chunk IDs are independent of threads and their execution. Thus, having 1 thread or 16 does not change the result. The order of the computed chunks does not change the result too. Note that each thread have its own local RNG (this is the way Numba works). Thus, I am not sure to understand your point.

Comment: My suggestion to use one PRNG to seed the others was not intended to "generate a better sequence." In fact, I was thinking just the opposite: I was thinking that it would be more convenient for the user of the program to supply a single number as the seed instead of a sequence of N numbers. But the price paid for that convenience would be a vastly smaller space of seeds from which to choose.

Comment: Ok. I did not think the user could tweak the seed for the computation. So this is a good idea indeed. An alternative is to do something like `np.random.seed(seed_base + chunk_id)` before computing each chunk instead of just `np.random.seed(chunk_id)` where `seed_base` would be the provided seed. This is not great because a slight change does not produce very different results. An improvement would be to hash seed_base or generate one random number based on it. In the end, this is similar to what you propose except the sequence is generated on the fly.